# How to force 'bundle update' to use :ruby as platform in Ruby 2.0 on Windows?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

As we know, ruby 2.0 on Windows has some problems which cause us have to install `platform=ruby` version instead of `platform=x86-mingw32` version gems.

I've added `--platform=ruby` in `.gemrc`.  Now when I install gems with `gem install / update`, it will install `ruby` version.  But this seems not affect bundler.  When I try to use `bundle install / update`, it will still install `x86-mingw32` version.

If `x86-mingw32` version exist in my system (even a `ruby` version also exist), `bundle exec` will use it, then my application will fail.  Many libs have such problem, e.g. do_sqlite3, http_parser.rb, bcrypt-ruby, etc.

Now i have to use `gem uninstall` to remove the `x86-mingw32` version manually almost every time I executed `bundle update`.

Is there any system-wide way to override bundler's platform? .xxxrc file? config file? ENV variables? Or even modify the source codes of bundler?

P.S. I've tried to modify the `PLATFORM` field in `Gemfile.lock` but no use.  Adding `:platforms => 'ruby'` in Gemfile is also unhelpful (actually any gem marked as `:platforms => 'ruby'` will not be installed on Windows)...

Thanks!

Comment: A quick note: If you want to do ruby on rails in windows you are in for a rough time. A unix based system is much easier to work with for rails development.

Comment: @Cort3z Thanks, but i was not using rails recently. :)

Comment: Note from 2022: now there is force_ruby_platform bundler option. Just tested it in my msys2 UCRT env, worked as advertised. https://bundler.io/man/bundle-config.1.html#LIST-OF-AVAILABLE-KEYS